# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2}$

Tags: analysis, limits, infinity

I am trying to evaluate
$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2}.
$$
I'd say it tends to 0, 1 or something linked to $e$ but I have no clue how to prove this... I'm getting really stuck as I try to clarify things. Can you hint me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(1+1/x)^x \to e$, this $\to \infty$.

Added: I read the limit as $\infty$, not $-\infty$. In this case,
if $y=-x$
so $y \to +\infty$,
$(1+1/x)^x
= 1/(1-1/y)^y
 \to 1/(1/e)
=e$,
so this $\to e^x =e^(-y)
=1/e^y \to 0$.

Comment: not to 0? isn't $x \to -\infty$?

Comment: I noticed this (before your comment) and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use substitution:

$$y=-x\implies x\to-\infty\iff y\to\infty\;,\;\;\text{and thus}:$$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x^2}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac1y\right)^y\right]^y=0$$

since

$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac ay\right)^y=e^a\;\;\forall\,a\in\Bbb R$$